# What is the benefit of repeating history in ARIES recovery method?

Tags: database, algorithm, rdbms, recovery, aries

In the [ARIES algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_Recovery_and_Isolation_Exploiting_Semantics), why does it need to repeat all the  history before the crash in the redo pass?
Can I get the committed Transaction Numbers during the analysis pass and then just redo the committed transactions log record? This method will reduce the number of record both need to redo and undo.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer:

We need to repeat all the history before the crash in the redo pass in order to ensure the database consistency before performing the undo pass.

### Long answer:

The [recovery algorithm ARIES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_Recovery_and_Isolation_Exploiting_Semantics), in order to ensure the atomicity and the durability properties of the DBMS, performs 3 passes:

1. **Analysis pass**: to see what needs to be done (plays log forward)
2. **Redo pass**: to make sure the disk reﬂects any updates that are in the log but not on disk including those that belong to transactions that will eventually be rolled back. This way it ensures we are in ***consistent state***, which will allow logical undo.
3. **Undo pass**: to remove the actions of any losing transactions

The UNDO data log is logical, while the REDO data log is physical:

- We must do physical REDO, since we can't guarantee that the database is in a consistent state (so, e.g., logging "INSERT VALUE X INTO TABLE Y" might not be a good idea, because X might be reﬂected in an index but not the table, or vice versa, in case a crash happens while inserting)
- We can do logical UNDO, because after REDO we know that things are consistent. In fact, we must do logical UNDO because we only UNDO some actions, and physical logging of UNDOs of the form, e.g., "split page x of index y" might not be the right thing to do anymore in terms of index management or invariant maintenance. We don't have to worry about this during redo because we repeat history and replay everything, which means any physical modiﬁcations made to the database  last time will still be correct.

[Source](http://db.csail.mit.edu/6.830/notes.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because ARIES is designed to work with a no-force/steal approach. The "steal" part means that changes from an uncommited transaction might be written to disk. Therefore we need to redo all transactions, both commited and uncommited, so we can undo the uncommited ones.

Comment: Thanks. I found a more reasonable answer.  To support the fine grain  lock , it has to redo all the updates even which is in an uncommitted update. This is described in the section 10.1 of ARIES paper and compare with the selective redo method.